# Create images with Devstack/Openstack

Tags: openstack, cloud

I have the following question.
After I installed Devstack on a Virtual Maschine, running Ubuntu 16.04, 
my goal was to provide hard drive space and RAM space for other computers in my network.

Does anybody know how to do this or is there a tutorial for this?
I was not able to find a good source to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I used Vagrant to create the VM where I installed devstack. Before I had this plug-in to vagrant (https://github.com/sprotheroe/vagrant-disksize) in order to be able to increase disk size similarly than we do in Vagrantfile (listed down) for fixing Ram size and it works quite well.

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Subnet="192.168.88"
Name="devstack"
Domain="dev"

VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|

  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/xenial64"

  config.disksize.size = '100GB'

  config.vm.define :"#{Name}" do |machine|
machine.vm.network :private_network, ip: "#{Subnet}.0"
machine.vm.hostname = "#{Name}.#{Domain}"
machine.ssh.insert_key = false

machine.vm.provider :virtualbox do |v|
v.memory = 15360
v.cpus = 4
end
end
end
```

Notice that it works only with Virtualbox as VM provider to vagrant.